# If statement inside include tag, smarty?

Tags: html, smarty, templating

I want to have an if statement (or something that can do the following functionality) inside a include tag in smarty. I have the following include tag:

```
        {include
        file="controls/control_input.tpl"
         //some other smarty variables
        mask=$itemType->mask
        mask=$field['mask']
        }
```

my goal is to essentially have mask be set to itemType->mask if field["mask"] is = to "", otherwise it should be set to field["mask"]. However, I am unable to have a if statement inside the include tag it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use if else condition before including template file and then pass mask variable inside include tag like this,

```html
{if $field['mask'] eq ""}
    {$mask = $itemType->mask}
{else}
    {$mask = $field['mask']}
{/if}

{include file="controls/control_input.tpl" mask=$mask}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else condition inside include statement

```
{include 
 file="controls/control_input.tpl"
        {if $item Type->mask}
        mask=$item Type->mask
        {else}mask=$field['mask']{/if}
        }
```